# How to retrieve data from Object using each loop by adding key value?

Tags: jquery, iteration, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have a url path, from the url I am getting base and sub url details. Using all this urls I would like to load the controllers to web site.

I have the ValidPath object separately. I am trying like this:

```
var ValidPaths = {
        "green":{
            "url":"greenController.js",
            "lightgreen" :{
                "url":"lightGreenController.js",
                "floragreen":{
                    "url":"floragreenController.js"
                }
            }
        }
    }
var path = ["green"].concat("lightgreen/floragreen".split('/'));
var finArr = [];

_.each(path, function(str,key){
    label += '["'+str+'"]';
    console.log(ValidPaths+label['url']); // i am not getting proper console details.
})
```

But I am getting wrong out put.
I am looking for my finArr should be like this:

```
//should be [ {"label":"green","url":"greenController.js"}, {"label":"lightgreen","url":"lightGreenController.js"},{"label":"floragreen","url":"floragreenController.js"}]
```

So I can iterate through temp engine. any one tell me what is the mistake i made here?

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/y68Y7/1/)

Comment: just made fiddle see:http://jsfiddle.net/d9bgY/

Comment: No this is wrong, I am getting same url details for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  user3558931,

```
 var paths = [path].concat(subPath.split('/')),
                    arr = [],prePath=ValidPaths;

                 function pathFinder (path,i){
                    if(prePath[path]){
                        arr.push({"label":path,"url":prePath[path]['url']});
                        prePath = prePath[path];
                    } else{
                        console.log("there is no path like " + path + "in ValidPaths");
                    }
                    return arr;
                }

                _.map(paths, function(root,i){
                    return pathFinder(root,i);
                });

                console.log("breadCrumb", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   var ValidPaths = {
        "green":{
            "url":"greenController.js",
            "lightgreen" :{
                "url":"lightGreenController.js",
                "floragreen":{
                    "url":"floragreenController.js"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    finArr = [],
       getNode = function(color, obj ) {
           var oPath = {}, i = 0;
           oPath.label = color;
           for( clr in obj ) {
               if( i === 0 ) {
                   oPath.url = obj[ clr ];
                   finArr.push( oPath );
               } else if( i === 1 ) {
                   getNode( clr, obj[ clr ] );
               }
               i++;
           }
       };
    for( clr in ValidPaths) {
        getNode( clr, ValidPaths[clr] );
    }
    console.log( finArr ); 
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/y68Y7/2/)

[This version](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/y68Y7/3/) is the shortest I could get it to. Any shorter and I encountered 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Comment: It need to nested inside of others. because I am using this for module management. so I need to keep parent - child relation to identify and avoiding module collapse

Comment: I see. Let me see if I can figure it out. Please see updated code and working demo.

Comment: Where is updated demo? can you update properly please?

Comment: Right below my code above there's a link JSFiddle Demo.

Comment: Yes, got. thanks. But we need to think about shortening the code

Comment: I thought about that too. I am open to any ideas!